# Closing conection from pool in runtime oracle-data-source

Tags: java, spring, oracle, connection-pooling

I have legacy web application. Witch uses jdbcTemplate to execute stored procedures from DB (Oracle), procedures located at packages. Problem is, when database developers compiles that packages im getting Expceptions sometihng like existing state of packages been changed (ora 4061). and they does that 1 or 2 times per week. Then i have to restart application to restart pool. app uses OracleDataSource. i can't change anything at that db but can change pool manager. so the question is. is it possible to close that connection? not just return to pool. and get new connection(from pool) if that Exception apears? thanks !!

people sugested to re-execute that stored procedure when that error apears. It doest worked.

```
<bean id="ds_name" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
      destroy-method="close">
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true" />
    <property name="URL" value="****" />
    <property name="user" value="user" />
    <property name="password" value="pass" />
    <property name="connectionCacheProperties">
        <value>
            MinLimit:1
            MaxLimit:100
            InitialLimit:1
            ConnectionWaitTimeout:120
            InactivityTimeout:180
            ValidateConnection:true
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="ds_name" />
</bean>
```

Comment: What is your current connection pool?

Comment: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource

Comment: I meant hikari or c3p0? can you show configuration?

Comment: non of them. it uses oracleDS from ojdbc 6